# Intersection observer and scroll-snap scale animation doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css, intersection-observer

I was trying to animate the images in carousel made with `scroll-snap` and `IntersectionObserver`.

Even thought the intersection observer is observing the parent element which is not scaled, it doesn't work as expected. Scaling animation on the images does work (kind of), but jumps sporadicly or even skips the slides all together

```js
const images = document.querySelectorAll(".slide");
const io = new IntersectionObserver(
  (entries) => {
    entries.forEach((e) => {
      e.target.classList.toggle("show", e.isIntersecting);
      e.target.classList.toggle("hide", !e.isIntersecting);
    });
  },
  {
    rootMargin: "0px",
    threshold: 0.6
  }
);

images.forEach((e) => io.observe(e));
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#app {
  height: 300px;
  max-width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
  position: relative;
}

.slide {
  width: 100vw;
  object-position: center;
  scroll-snap-align: center;
  transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
}

.slide > img {
  object-fit: cover;
}

.show {
  opacity: 1;
}
.show img {
  transform: scale(1);
}

.hide {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.hide img {
  transform: scale(0.8);
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="https://cataas.com/cat/4" />
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="https://cataas.com/cat/9" />
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="https://cataas.com/cat/4" />
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="https://cataas.com/cat/9" />
  </div>
</div>
```